# Why my OpenShot Video Editor gets very slow every time (Win10)?

Tags: video-editor

I just started to use **OpenShot Video Editor** to concatenate some short videos I filmed with my phone and add a sound track recently. The task is quite simple. But the software seems to mess up with the CPU or Memory or something. It's smooth in the beginning of a project, and then after half an hour or so, my laptop always makes a lot of noise and asks me to wait via a circle for every operation I do, while everything else than OpenShot can still function properly.

Well this is a new laptop, and I don't know what **Task Manager** means by 31; there're only 5 to 6 tabs open in Google Chrome. I'm afraid I'm totally a layman in computer and electronics. Can anybody point out the problem for me, please?

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: It is probably not a video production topic. You seem to have not much free memory left at the time you took the screenshot. Maybe you ran out of memory at some point which makes the system use the much slower hard disk instead for storing what should go into the RAM. This typically slows down every application, like you have observed. However, it's difficult to diagnose this from afar, the RAM problem I described is just a likely guess, but it could be something else. If you can, ask sb. you trust and is well versed in computer matters to help you in person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go Edit, Preferences.
Your memory limit may be at 250mb
change it to 3000mb

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!